# Can we use PageFactory.initElements in Appium (Android)

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, appium

I am getting exception when try to use in Mobile automation using Appium. While it is working perfect for Web Testing automation.

```
*Given The app is opened                                                      # CommonSteps.OpenApp()
    Then I should see "Skip button" on welcome screen                            # WelcomeScreenSteps.CheckElementPresent(String)
      cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class steps.WelcomeScreenSteps
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:26)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:298)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:48)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:163)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:120)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:34)
        ... 11 more
      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: pages.Pages
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:66)
        at steps.WelcomeScreenSteps.<init>(WelcomeScreenSteps.java:16)
        ... 16 more
      Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: pages.Pages
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:133)
        ... 18 more*
```

Can we use PageFactory.initElements in Appium Mobile automation?

**Feature file:**

```
Feature: As a user, I want to open the app when not logged in and check the welcome screens
@TestTag
Scenario: Open app when not logged in and check 3 welcome screens using swipes
Given The app is opened
Then I should see "Skip button" on welcome screen
```

**Step File:**

```
public class WelcomeScreenSteps extends DriverStore {

    // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Pages pages = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Pages.class);
    //WelcomeSreenPage welcomeScreen = new WelcomeSreenPage(driver);

    public WelcomeScreenSteps() {
        // System.out.println("I am in Welcome Constructor");
    }
@Given("^the app is open$")
    public void the_app_is_open() throws Throwable {
        // Code to open the app
        System.out.println("in the step");
    }
@Then("^I should see \"(.*?)\" on welcome screen$")
    public void CheckElementPresent(String identifire) {
        Assert.assertTrue(pages.welcomeScreen.checkElementPresent(identifire));
    }
```

**Pages.java**

```
public class Pages {
    /*AppiumDriver driver;*/
    static AppiumDriver driver;

    public WelcomeSreenPage welcomeScreen = PageFactory.initElements(driver, WelcomeSreenPage.class);

    /*public Pages(AppiumDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }*/
    public Pages(AppiumDriver driver) {
        Pages.driver = driver;
    }

    public WelcomeSreenPage welcomeScreen() {
        welcomeScreen = new WelcomeSreenPage(driver);
        return welcomeScreen;
    }
}
```

**WelcomeScreenPage.java**

```
public class WelcomeSreenPage {
// all mobile element identifier here
    // WebDriver driver;
    AppiumDriver driver;
public boolean checkElementPresent(String identifire) {
        MobileElement element = actions.getElement(mapElement(identifire),
                driver);
        if (element != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code snippet and the exception stack?

Comment: I have updated my description with code snippet and exception stack

Answer (score 0):

This Working with Me, My Project Selenium, TestNG and Appium use PageFactory.initElements

```
public class Login extends Setup {

    @Test
    public void loginAlert() throws InterruptedException {
        

    Button button = new Button(driver);
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, button);
            Input input = new Input(driver);
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, input);
        
        
        Input input1 = new Input(driver);
        System.out.println("Test Alert Login");
        button.ById("navigation_more");
        button.ById("btnLogin");
        input.ById("et_email_or_phone_number", "dikakoko.com");
        input1.ById("tet_password", "dikakoko");
        
    }
}
```

Below this is the function I called above.

```
public class Input {
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    Root root = new Root();

    public Input(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void ById(String selector, String textValue) {
        MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(root.element() + ":id/" + selector));
        waitForVisible(driver, element);
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.click();
        actions.sendKeys(textValue);
        actions.build().perform();
        System.out.println("Input: " + textValue);
    }
    
    private void waitForVisible(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver, MobileElement element) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Waiting for element visibility");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and This

```
public class Button {

    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    Root root = new Root();

    public Button(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void ById(String selector) {
        MobileElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(root.element() + ":id/" + selector));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element);
        actions.click();
        actions.build().perform();
        System.out.println("Button is Clicked!");
    }
}
```

I Use This

```
Button button = new Button(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, button);
Input input = new Input(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, input);
```

My References : [From www.seleniumeasy.com](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/page-factory-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver)